# upload error on Apache

Tags: php, apache, file-upload

I don't really know much PHP. But anyways I am not able to upload a .csv file using the following php. I have fixed the problem with upload_max size related attributes. Works fine on my local but not on sandbox. Is it file type problem?

I can only get it to print something like this... which is not helpful at all.
"-- CSV file to load:  >>> NOT a file valid: 1 "

where should I fix? How do I print a complete PHP error message instead of just the value "1" which I'm not sure what it corresponds to? ie... output more useful print like this "UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE: 1"?

```
<?php
// using upload at click from http://code.google.com/p/upload-at-click/
// FileData is the name for the input file

$file_result = "";
$file = $_FILES['Filedata'];

$allowedExtensions = array("csv", "txt");
$arrayVar = explode(".", $file["name"]);
$extension = end($arrayVar);

//commented out for “Only variables should be passed by reference” error
//$extension = end(explode(".", $file["name"]));


function isAllowedExtension($fileName) {
    global $allowedExtensions;
    return in_array(end(explode(".", $fileName)), $allowedExtensions);
}

if($file["error"] > 0){
    echo "failure to upload the file >>> ". "Error code: ".$file["error"]."<br>";
}else{
    //echo " >>> CURRENT DIR: ".getcwd() . "\n";
    $workDir = getcwd();

    $dir = substr($workDir, 0, -10);
    $path = $file["name"];
    $newFileLoc = $dir.$path;

    $file_result.=
    "<br>     Upload: " . $file["name"] . "<br>" .
    "     Type: " . $file["type"] . "<br>" .
    "     Size: " . $file["size"] . "<br>" .
    "     file uploaded to: ".$newFileLoc."<br>";

    // txt - text/plain
    // rtf - application/msword
    // dat/obj - application/octet-stream
    // csv - application/vnd.ms-excel
    // maximum 200 MB file - 200,000,000 k

    if (    ($file["type"] == "application/vnd.ms-excel" || $file["type"] == "text/plain")
            && isAllowedExtension($file["name"])
            && ($file["size"] < 200000000)
        )
        {   
            move_uploaded_file($file["tmp_name"], $newFileLoc);
            //echo $file_result.=" >>> File uploaded successfull!!";
            echo "|".$path;//"filePath : " . $newFileLoc;

        }else{
            echo " >>> NOT a file valid: ". isAllowedExtension($file["name"]);
        }       
}
?>
```

This is the line that was added as suggested by another user to catch the error correctly. Please let me know if that's right sorry i don't know much PHP at all. Anyways, the error printed is just "-- CSV file to load:  >>> NOT a file valid: 1 "

```
<?php
// using upload at click from http://code.google.com/p/upload-at-click/
// FileData is the name for the input file

ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);

$file_result = "";
$file = $_FILES['Filedata'];

$allowedExtensions = array("csv", "txt");
$arrayVar = explode(".", $file["name"]);
$extension = end($arrayVar);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The block in question is the following:

```
if( ( $file["type"] == "application/vnd.ms-excel" || $file["type"] == "text/plain" ) && 
    isAllowedExtension($file["name"]) && 
    ( $file["size"] < 200000000 ) )
{   
    move_uploaded_file($file["tmp_name"], $newFileLoc);

    //echo $file_result.=" >>> File uploaded successfull!!";

    echo "|".$path;//"filePath : " . $newFileLoc;
}
else
{
    echo " >>> NOT a file valid: ". isAllowedExtension($file["name"]);
}
```

Note that you're hitting your else `echo`, and the '1' is because `isAllowedExtension()` is returning a boolean, which is true, which is denoted as '1' (as opposed to '0') when you print it.

One of your conditions in the `if` there are failing. I'd separate them out a bit, and see which in particular is.

**EDIT** For example:

```
if( ( $file["type"] == "application/vnd.ms-excel" || $file["type"] == "text/plain" ) )
{
    if( isAllowedExtension($file["name"]) )
    {
        if( $file["size"] < 200000000 )
        {
            move_uploaded_file($file["tmp_name"], $newFileLoc);

            echo "|".$path;//"filePath : " . $newFileLoc;
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Invalid file size: " . $file["size"] . "\n";   
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Invalid extension: " . $file["name"] . "\n";   
    }    
}
else
{
    echo "Invalid type: " . $file["type"] . "\n";
}
```

Alternatively, you can just `print_r()` `$file` and see what it's values are.

Comment: nice, thanks alot for the update. I updated the php according to your suggestion. It's much more clear this way. But now getting a new error "-- CSV file to load:  Invalid type: application/octet-stream"